# On which Windows systems are Command Extensions disabled by default?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

According to this page on [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) Windows batch command, Command Extensions are enabled by default. Are there any Windows systems where it is not enable by default? Do I really need to explicitly include  `setlocal EnableExtensions` in any of my batch scripts?

Comment: If the scripts are going to be run on other people's computers (shame on you!) then yes, you probably need to turn command extensions on explicitly.  If they're only for in-house use, you probably don't need to bother.  Check with whoever administers the computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can always be disabled in the registry and if that's possible there are probably systems where it's the case. I haven't found any such system, though.